# Не могу разобраться, в чём ошибка MySQL БД

Tags: php, mysql, json, windows, apache

Есть файл json, который через php-скрипт отправляется в базу данных и записывается в одну из ячеек. При этом получаю периодически похожие ошибки:

> [Mon Feb 14 02:38:00.632563 2022] [php:error] [pid 8316:tid 12364] [client *****] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9, \xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd1\x83 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc \xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x8f\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8b\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5, \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1' at line 1 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Loc\Php\VstavitJson.php:14\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\Loc\Php\VstavitJson.php(14): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE LeagueOf...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Loc\Php\VstavitJson.php on line 14

В самом файле json могут встречаться русские буквы. Вроде бы на них и ругается ошибка, но я не понимаю, как это исправить. У кого-то есть идеи?

Код VstavitJson.php:

```php
<?php

include('ConfigLoD.php');

if (isset($_POST)) 
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $histjson= $_POST['histjson'];
      


$sql = "UPDATE LeagueOfDreamers SET histjson = '$histjson' WHERE id= '$id' ";  

if (mysqli_query($db, $sql))
 {
   echo "histjson успешно обновлена";
} 
else 
{
   echo "Ошибка Json обновления записи: " . mysqli_error($db);
}
}


?>
```

Comment: перед вставкой данных в БД, сами данные надо экранировать.

Comment: Проверьте кодировку в которой Вы присылаете на сервер `json` и кодировку `БД`.

Comment: Проверяйте CHARSET сервера, клиента, соединения... добавьте требуемый SET NAMES в дополнительные команды соединения.

Comment: Если в $_POST['histjson'] в середине текста придёт кавычка, что получится в $sql? А если после кавычки будет ```;DROP TABLE ОченьНужнаяТаблица; ```? Не надо так писать в базу напрямую.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно проблема была в одинарной кавычке. Решили её убрать. histjson отправляется без участия пользователя и он не имеет возможности перед отправкой что-то в нём поменять, так как он формируется в момент отправки. Но ваше замечание учтём!